# Intellij difference colour meanings

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij I right clicked on a file and clicked "Git -> Compare with Latest Repository Version" to open up the diff viewer. Is there a list somewhere of what all of the different highlight colours are? I know that if text on the right is green that it means that it has been added, and if text is grey on the left then it's been removed from the current version, but what does a pale blue highlight mean?

In the Intellij documentation I've found this link that describes the different options you can choose, but it doesn't say anything about what the different higlight colours mean.

For reference here are the three colours I can see.

green
[image: Intellij diff viewer green highlight]
grey
[image]
blue
[image: Intellij diff viewer blue highlight]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of IntelliJ you are using, but in version 11, which I use, there is a legend at the bottom of the diff window which looks like this:

[image]

**Pale blue means that the line has been changed.**

Comment: When I look at the About Intellij section it says I'm using Intellij Community Edition 2016.1.3 . Where did you get version 11 from? Mine doesn't have that bar.

Comment: I have been running version 11 for a number of years as this is what my license gets me.  As of fairly recently, it was possible to download version 11 from the JetBrains website.